# Regex match on rubular but not in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to return `"A1RKKUPIHCS9HS"` from string `cheese`:

```
cheese = "#<struct Peddler::Marketplace id=\"A1RKKUPIHCS9HS\",..."
```

I tried both `scan` and `match` like this:

```
cheese.match(/(?<=id=\\").{14}/)
cheese.scan(/(?<=id=\\")./)
```

It works on [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/ZczJV8RrBXeQoO), but when I try it in Ruby, it doesn't. No idea why.

Comment: There are no backslashes in the string, but you are trying to match them with ``\\`` in the regex, remove the ``\\`` from the regex.

Comment: You can also write `cheese[cheese.index('"')+1, 14] #=> "A1RKKUPIHCS9HS"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `cheese[cheese.index('id="')+4, 14]` if you want to mimic the regexp approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following as your test string at Rubular:

```
#<struct Peddler::Marketplace id="A1RKKUPIHCS9HS",...
```

That is, do not put the string in double quotes or escape double quotes within the string. Rubular will take care of that, just as it surrounds your regex with two forward slashes.

You want your regex to be `/(?<=id=").{14}/`. That's the same as `/(?<=id=\").{14}/` since the double quote need not be escaped, but escaping it leaves it unchanged and therefore does no harm. Ruby treats double (and single) quotes with the regex as ordinary characters with no special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `.scan(/id="(.{14})"/)` as a simpler way.

Comment: What is the point of escaping the first double quote but not the second?

Comment: Oops fixed my regexp, actually no need for backslashes, it's just ruby when inspecting a string that shows the backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, using [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
cheese = "#<struct Peddler::Marketplace id=\"A1RKKUPIHCS9HS\",..."
cheese[/(?<=id=").*?(?=")/]
#⇒ "A1RKKUPIHCS9HS"
```